# Pass parameters through the stack

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16, emu8086

I'm writing a program with emu8086

```
.data
address   dd 82C028D1h, 81C0276Ah 
mask      dd FFFC0000h
reference dd 82C0B685h

.code
proc filter
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    ; stack              

    ; bp+0  ==> old bp

    ; bp+2  ==> return address 
    ; bp+4  ==> return value
    ; bp+6  ==> offset mask
    ; bp+8  ==> offset address
    ; bp+10 ==> low reference
    ; bp+12 ==> high reference
    ....
    pop bp
    ret
    endp
```

In my "main" code I have

```
; intel is LITTLE ENDIAN
push WORD PTR [reference+2]    ; high
push WORD PTR [reference]  ; low 

push offset address
push offset mask  

sub sp, 2    ; space for return value
call filter
pop ax       ; return value

add sp, 8    ; clean parameters
```

It seems like my assumptions on where the parameters are on the stack are wrong, how can I access my parameters?

**EDIT**

Full code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hNRA8rqs).

I have an array "address", a mask and a reference. I need to check, for every element of address, if it matches the reference according to the mask (1 or 0).
If I find a particular bit I need to check (1 in mask) that doesn't match, my element is invalid.

I have to return how many addresses are valid.

**Example**:

*reference* : 10000010.11000000.10110110.10000101

*mask*      : 11111111.11111100.00000000.00000000

*address1*  : 10000010.11000000.00101000.11010001 (valid)

*address2*  : 10000001.11000000.00100111.01101010 (not valid)

Comment: Your assumptions are right. Did you initialize `DS` (`mov ax,@data`; `mov ds, ax`)? In the EMU8086 emulator window you can click on "stack" on the bottom and you get another window with the actual values of the stack and the position of `sp`..

Comment: just before the "main" I have a '.startup'. For all the programs I have written so far I never needed to initialize DS.

Comment: oh wait, the `sub sp,2` was for return value, not address... ok, then your map is OK, sorry. You still should use the debugger to verify it, though.  ... the `.startup` is TASM macro, needs `.model` to operate properly, and verify in debugger if emu8086 even supports it, maybe it silently ignores it. It all boils down to comparing few values in `ss`, `ds`, `bp`, `sp`, `cs:ip`, etc... to figure out, if your code is actually hitting the expected memory area, or wandering somewhere off...

Comment: @Ped7g I do "sub sp, 2" not for the return address, but to make space to return a value. Both call and ret manage return address for me

Comment: Yes, I also have .model and the others macros. If my assumptions are right maybe I made some mistake in my code in a later point

Comment: Yes, the part of code you posted looks correct, after re-reading it. I will delete my original comments. The part about learning how to use debugger is ESSENTIAL. Stop everything else and start to toy around with the emu8086 debugger to learn to use it at least at some basic level. After that it will be much easier for you to develop in assembly, and check what your code REALLY does. ... BTW [MCVE] helps a lot, really (i.e. posting small example which can be actually compiled, run, and you describe well what inputs/outputs you have and what is wrong about them)

Comment: I posted my full code with a description of what I have to do.

Comment: I found out I need a "WORD PTR" before [bp+4]. Anyway I can get the right reference but not the mask and address. Maybe a problem dereferencing the offset?

Comment: `address` is a confusing name for a pointer to an output buffer.  Especially when you're passing a pointer to it right next to the function's return address (which will be consumed by `ret`).  Maybe call it `outbuf`.

Comment: I wrongly used the square brackets to access in memory... now everything works. Thanks